# jQuery ui: Draggable, How do I determin how much on the x-axis an image was moved ?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, resize, draggable

I have an image inside a div, like so:

```
<div><img src="" class="draggable"></div>
```

It's a draggable image, through jQuery UI. Now I want to determin how much the image is moved on the x-axis, so I can use that info to save the position of the image.

I.E. If the image is moved 100px left, x should be "-100px", and if it's moved to the right it should be "100px"..

I can use this, but it only determin how much the image was moved, not in a specific direction:

```
drag: function() {
                counts[ 1 ]++;
                updateCounterStatus( $drag_counter, counts[ 1 ] );
            },
```

Whats the solution ?

Thanks, 
Jakob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, if you want to save the image position when you stop dragging the image. Simply just check left and top of the image on stop:

```
stop: function(event, ui) { 
    var topValue = $(this).position().top;
    var leftValue = $(this).position().left;
    //Save them to wherever you want
}
```

jQuery UI's draggable isn't doing anything magic, if you inspect it in Firebug or Chrome Dev Toolbar you will see that all it does is to alter the left and top property of the element.

More information about the different events that Draggable have: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events

Comment: You should use `.offset().top` and `.offset().left` to retrieve position instead of the CSS attributes, which might not exist on all DOM elements.

Comment: Depends on the situation, if you would store the offset() values persistent and recreate them at the jquery demos you would notice that the box gets placed in the wrong position.

But I agree with you, should use either offset() or position() to get the values in a more proper way.

Answer (score 2):

I would store the start position on start and compute the difference on stop like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/FMC56/1

```
$( "#drag" ).draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).data("startx",$(this).offset().left)
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var change = $(this).offset().left - $(this).data("startx");
        this.innerHTML = "change: " + change + "px";
    }
});
```

EDIT: using data was mblase75's idea btw.

Comment: OP didn't ask for it, but determining the overall distance moved (instead of only x-distance) is as easy as employing the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: Also, if OP is using more than one draggable, globals won't work well, but the numbers could be stored as `.data` attributes on the DIV itself.